# How to prevent nodejs from throwing an error when requiring data from a vanilla js file that uses the window object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

I'm trying to send a specific piece of an array from a vanilla javascript file to a nodejs file by using module.exports. Since the window and document objects do not exist in nodejs, my nodejs file throws 'ReferenceError: window is not defined' every time I run it.

Is it possible to have node ignore everything in the js file except for the array piece? Are there any other ways to go about this or is sending data through module.exports when browser objects are present impossible? I'm very new to node and fairly new to javascript so let me know if I'm missing something obvious.

My vanilla js code

```
 window.onload = function(){
       events();
 };

 var dayID = [];

 function events(){

     td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

    var days =[td[3],td[4],td[5],td[6],td[7],td[8],td[9],td[10],td[11],td[12],td[13],td[14],td[15],td[16],td[17],td[18],td[19],td[20],td[21],td[22],td[23],td[24],td[25],td[26],td[27],td[28],td[29],td[30]];

    for ( var i in days){

            days[i].addEventListener("click", send);

            function send(){
                    dayID.splice(0,1,this);console.log(dayID[0].textContent);
            }
    }
}

module.exports.day = dayID[0]
```

My nodejs code

```
 x = require('./app.js');

 console.log(x.day);
```

Comment: you can't use `window` object in nodejs. here the first line will through an error and rest of the code won't execute. also you need to declare `send` function in global scope to export it.

Comment: your vanilla js code has nothing at all useful for node - and the last line is completely wrong

Comment: To siam - yes I already know that there is no window object in node, as stated in my description. Also, the send function is already in global scope.

Comment: To Jaromanda X - what Im trying to do is send over data retrieved from a click on a page to the backend (nodejs) and trigger a myql query that uses that data I just sent. If I can't do this with module.exports, do you have any suggestions for other ways I can accomplish this?

Comment: Add `global.window = {}` before you require that file.